# How can I retrieve a file from my app folder in android?

Tags: android

I want to send the database file of my app via email. This makes my it easier to help in a error case. For that I need to retrieve the installation folder of my app. How can I achieve this so that i can send my db which is place here APP-FOLDER\databases\mydb.db

Thanks

Comment: Friend there are lots of code to do this just do proper googling and you will get code.

Comment: I do not ask questions here without searched a bit before!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you are asking about the strategy or where to start to do so.

There are several approaches you can follow,

1) **Save your db file to the sdcard** then it will be available to you for your mailing function. You can achieve this by using `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(String, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)`  and simply pass `"/sdcard/yrdatabase.db"` as the first parameter .

2) If you aren't saving it to the sdcard, then **simply move your db file to the sdcard**. You can achieve this by using following code. (i.e. bind the below function to your button or anyhow call it from your app)

```
public void copyDBToSDCard() {
    try {
        InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.yrproject/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+DATABASE_NAME);
        if (!file.exists()){
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("TAG","File creation failed for " + file);
            }
        }

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/"+DATABASE_NAME);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Log.i("TAG","copied");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TAG","exception="+e);
    }

}
```

Once you are done with the accessing `db` file, you can use mail functions to use it further.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just thinking what is when the app has been moved to the sdcard? Then this wont work, or?

Comment: When app has moved, Google Doc says : "The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory."
For more details, you can refer this link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: My pleasure. If it is helpful, you can accept this as an answer.